# Dynamic filter based on conditionalPanel in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am not familiar with Shiny and was wondering if you could help me with dynamic filtering. Based on tutorials I've read, I was able to come up with this so far. The issue that I'm running into is that the "Freq" is not changing dynamically when specific Dept, gender and admit type is selected. Essentially, I would like the Freq to decrease into one value when every field has a selection. How can I get the user selection under the "Select gender" section and "Select Admit type:" so that I can use it to index the dataframe? Thank you.

```
library(shiny)

Admit<-c("Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted",
         "Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected","Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected",
         "Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted" ,"Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected")
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Female", "Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female", "Male","Male","Female","Female",
          "Male","Male","Female","Female","Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female","Male","Male","Female","Female")
Dept<-c( "A","A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F")
Freq<-c("512", "313",  "89",  "19", "353", "207",  "17",   "8", "120", "205", "202", "391", "138", "279", "131", "244",  "53", "138",
        "94", "299",  "22", "351",  "24", "317")

df<-data.frame(Admit,Gender,Dept, Freq)

#df<-data.frame(UCBAdmissions)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("UC Berkley Admissions"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Apply Filter to achieve desired results."),

      selectInput('Dept', choices = c("-",df$Dept), label = 'Select a Dept'), 

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Dept != '-'",
                       uiOutput("select_Dept"),
                       uiOutput("select_Admit"),
                       uiOutput("Freq"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("Add Data here later"),)
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$select_Dept <- renderUI({
    choices<-unique(df$Gender)
    checkboxGroupInput('Projects', label = 'Select Gender',
                       choices = choices)
  })

  output$select_Admit<-renderUI({
    Admit<-unique(df$Admit)
    checkboxGroupInput('Projects', label = 'Select Admit Type:',
                       choices = Admit) 
  })

  output$Freq<-renderUI({
    Freq<-sort(df$Freq[grep(input$Dept,df$Dept)])
    selectInput('sample', choices =Freq, label ='Select Freq')
  })
}


# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Having a bit of your data to work with would make this an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make it easier for others to help test your app and figure out why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Agree with phalteman. We are unable to run this on our own machines to diagnose this issue. Please provide your data (or a representative subset of your data) using `dput` so we can pick it up and run your test app. Thanks :)

Comment: I failed to mention that UCBAdmissions is a dataset that comes with R core. I assumed that you would be able to run the code without issue. Sorry about that. I will edit my question to include the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things may help in your example:

For `selectInput` for Department, you probably want to use `levels` of `df$Dept` instead of just including `df$Dept` (all data).

With that change, `Select Freq` will work somewhat, but won't filter based on `Admit` or `Gender`. To filter based on all three (Dept, Admit, Gender), would make a separate `reactive` function to filter your data.

Hope this is helpful.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("UC Berkley Admissions"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Apply Filter to achieve desired results."),
      selectInput('Dept', choices = c("-", levels(df$Dept)), label = 'Select a Dept'), 
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Dept != '-'",
                       uiOutput("select_Dept"),
                       uiOutput("select_Admit"),
                       uiOutput("Freq"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("Add Data here later"))
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  Freq <- reactive({
    subset1 <- df[grep(input$Dept, df$Dept), ]
    subset2 <- subset1[(df$Admit %in% input$ProjectAdmit) & (df$Gender %in% input$ProjectGender), ]
    return(sort(subset2$Freq))
  })

  output$select_Dept <- renderUI({
    choices<-unique(df$Gender)
    checkboxGroupInput('ProjectGender', label = 'Select Gender:',
                       choices = choices)
  })

  output$select_Admit<-renderUI({
    Admit<-unique(df$Admit)
    checkboxGroupInput('ProjectAdmit', label = 'Select Admit Type:',
                       choices = Admit) 
  })

  output$Freq<-renderUI({
    selectInput('sample', choices =Freq(), label ='Select Freq')
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! Now I understand why the selection for the ```selectInput``` for the department is showing up as 1-6. I will look more into the reactive function to see how I can filter based on Admit or Gender. It looks like I need to figure out how to auto select every field on the ProjectGender and ProjectAdmit checkboxes when a department is chosen so that you can see every Freq. Then unselecting specific checkboxes can then filter the data. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great - glad to hear. If you want to select all checkboxes as the default, you can do: `choices = choices, selected = choices` in your `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: Thanks again for guiding me in the right direction.